# Como selecionar TODAS as linhas que tenham um valor que exceda 3 ou -3 em um dataframe pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data.frame

Seja:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4))
```

Eu encontrei o seguinte para selecionar TODAS as linhas que tenham um valor que exceda 3 ou -3:

```
data[(np.abs(data) >3).any(1)]
```

Não entendi o parâmetro 1 do Any():

Qualquer outro valor no lugar do 1, gera erros!
Há alguma outra forma de fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na página de ajuda da função informa que as entradas da função são:

```
DataFrame.any(self, axis=0, bool_only=None, skipna=True, level=None, **kwargs).
```

O parâmetro que a função está pegando como valor 1 é axis.

```
axis : {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’, None}, default 0.
```

Ou seja, o parâmero só aceita 0 ou 1. Se você rodar o comando `np.abs(data) >3).any(0)` terá como resposta abaixo, pois ele fará um teste agrupado por coluna:

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
dtype: bool
```

Dará erro, pois para filtrar um frame de 1000 linhas seria necessário uma lista de 1000 elementos com valores True ou False.

Se você transpor o DataFrame e aplicar a pesquisa com 0 irá funcionar:

```
>>> data.T[(np.abs(data) >3).any()]
        0         1         2         3         4    ...       995       996       997       998       999
0  1.450311  1.192274  0.221418  0.154094  1.182402  ... -0.114990  0.022501  1.450387 -0.148182  1.176990
1  1.366100 -1.103633 -0.736515 -1.032142  0.324770  ...  0.367205  0.229713  0.913765 -0.495397  0.943025
2 -0.657914  0.732565 -1.034729  1.256725  0.556723  ...  0.105583 -0.357065 -0.907179 -0.709269 -2.395450
3 -0.611006  0.628155  1.463978 -0.261827 -0.964198  ...  0.338030  1.421146 -1.490041  0.030427  0.887882

[4 rows x 1000 columns]
```

Comment: Esse any do pandas é bem diferente do any do python, que é any(função, iteravel)...

Comment: Existe alguma outra forma de fazer a mesma seleção?

Comment: Acredito que a forma mais direta de fazer é essa, pois se quer fazer um teste do conjunto de dados de uma linha. Se fosse apenas testar apenas uma coluna, como por exemplo a coluna 0, poderia-se fazer "data[abs(data[0])>3]".